# Pass Swagger-UI url in drf-spectacular settings

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

I have a project written in `Django 2.x.` I want to add automatic documentation to it using **drf-spectacular**. I'm using `drf-spectacular=0.15.1` at the moment.

I'm running my project in Docker, and the build context for my api container is set as the root folder of the api project.

When I run the command to generate the schema, `./manage.py spectacular --file schema.yml`, the script creates a `schema.yml` file in the root of my api project, but my Django `settings.py` are found one level below, in a folder called `my_website`. The structure of the project is like this:

```
main-project
\api
 \_my_website
  __init__.py
  apps.py
  settings.py
  urls.py

 schema.yml

\client
docker-compose.yml
```

So in `settings.py` I added specific settings to tell Swagger-UI where from to take the schema, as specified in the `drf-spectacular` documentation:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
        'url': 'schema.yml'
    },
}
```

Once I try to access the swagger-ui url in my project to check that the schema is loaded there, I get the error: `**Fetch error** Not Found schema.yml`. I tried passing the schema url in various ways, for example through relative url `../schema.yml` but that didn't work either. Maybe somebody can give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing too much about Swagger UI, I'm going to bet this is a url, not a file reference and it's being fetched over http. Does Django or whatever is responsible for it in your docker setup serve this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [swagger-configuration doc](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/),

> **`url`**: The URL pointing to API definition (normally `swagger.json` or `swagger.yaml`)

thus, the `url` value must be either a "relative URL" or "absolute URL".

For example

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
        'url': 'https://example.com/path/to/schema/',  # absolute path
        'url': '/path/to/schema/',  # relative path
    },
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing as well in my settings file, I didn't realize that after I was configuring the url in urls.py I had to use the url I already set up there to retrieve my schema. Thanks!